# Value - property and attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I tried to update `input` element's value using `.val()` and it turned out that it doesn't affect the `value=""` attribute. After reading some topics here on stackoverflow, it turned out that these are not the same.

I started changing them both to be sure I do not do any mistake there:
`$("#elementid").val(variableNumber).attr('value', variableNumber);`

Now, lets say that I am sending the value of my `input` to validate it in php.
Which of these will be sent ff I make them different?

```
$("elementid").val(variable1);
$("elementid").attr('value', variable2);
```

Is there any rule on this? or any factor that makes one of these being sent as the actual "value" ?

Comment: The property gets sent. The fact that the attribute doesn't get changed in the DOM makes no difference as it's the intended behaviour. I wouldn't even bother setting it manually, as it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of these will be sent ff I make them different?

The input's *current value* will be sent. The current value is reflected by the the [`value` *property*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value). The [`value` *attribute*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-value) represents the *default value* of the input, not its current value (and is reflected as the `defaultValue` property on the `input`). The default value is used to initialize the value when the `input` is created, and to reset it if you use the `reset` method of a form it's in.

Unless you want to change the default value, there's no need to set the `value` attribute, just the property. The property is what `val` changes, what changes when the user acts on the input, and what gets sent when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you. After 2 days of racking my brains, you explained it to me in an understandable way and it took you like 1 minute haha. Thanks once again

Comment: Sir, would you mind to tell me where the property value is hidden in html? I am not sure if it is possible to find it anywhere

Comment: @divHelper11: The `value` property isn't in the HTML at all. HTML defines the element and its default value (via the `value` attribute), but not its *current* value.

Answer (score 1):

When you are working with `<input type='text'>` I think you should use `attr('value', variableNumber);` instead of `val(value)`.

`val(value)` is useful when working on a jQuery object containing elements like `<input type="checkbox">`, `<input type="radio">`, and `<option>s` inside of a `<select>`. More infomation [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).